# Хук клавиатуры не работает под другим пользователем

Tags: c#

Для отлова нажатия клавиш использую хук через WinAPI.

```
public sealed class GlobalHook : IDisposable
{
// Импортируем необходимые функции WinAPI, объявляем нужные для них структуры и константы
private static class WinAPI
{
    public static class Kernel32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
    }

    public static class User32
    {
        // KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644967(v=vs.85).aspx
        public struct KeyboardHookStruct
        {
            public uint VKCode;
            public uint ScanCode;
            public uint Flags;
            public uint Time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        // MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx
        public struct MouseHookStruct
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;
            public uint MouseData;
            public uint Flags;
            public uint Time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        // Константы WH_*
        public enum WindowsHook : int
        {
            KeyboardLowLevel = 13,
            MouseLowLevel = 14,
        }

        // Константы WM_*
        public enum WindowsMessage : int
        {
            KeyDown = 0x100,
            KeyUp = 0x101,

            SysKeyDown = 0x104,
            SysKeyUp = 0x105,

            MouseMove = 0x200,
            LeftButtonDown = 0x201,
            LeftButtonUp = 0x202,

            RightButtonDown = 0x204,
            RightButtonUp = 0x205,

            MiddleButtonDown = 0x207,
            MiddleButtonUp = 0x208,
        }

        public delegate int KeyboardHookProc(int code,
            WindowsMessage wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public delegate int MouseHookProc(int code,
            WindowsMessage wParam, ref MouseHookStruct lParam);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHk, int nCode,
            WindowsMessage wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHk, int nCode,
            WindowsMessage wParam, ref MouseHookStruct lParam);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(WindowsHook idHook,
            KeyboardHookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(WindowsHook idHook,
            MouseHookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHk);
    }
}

// Дескрипторы хуков
private readonly IntPtr _keyboardHookHandle;
private readonly IntPtr _mouseHookHandle;

// Хуки
private readonly WinAPI.User32.KeyboardHookProc _keyboardCallback;
private readonly WinAPI.User32.MouseHookProc _mouseCallback;

// События
public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown = (s, e) => { };
public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp = (s, e) => { };
public event MouseEventHandler MouseButtonDown = (s, e) => { };
public event MouseEventHandler MouseButtonUp = (s, e) => { };
public event MouseEventHandler MouseMove = (s, e) => { };

public GlobalHook()
{
    // Создадим колбэки и сохраним их в полях класса, чтобы их не собрал GC
    _keyboardCallback = new WinAPI.User32.KeyboardHookProc((int code,
        WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage wParam, ref WinAPI.User32.KeyboardHookStruct lParam) =>
    {
        // Если code < 0, мы не должны обрабатывать это сообщение системы
        if (code >= 0)
        {
            var key = (Keys)lParam.VKCode;
            var eventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(key);

            // В зависимости от типа пришедшего сообщения вызовем то или иное событие
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.KeyDown:
                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.SysKeyDown:
                    KeyDown(this, eventArgs);
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.KeyUp:
                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.SysKeyUp:
                    KeyUp(this, eventArgs);
                    break;
            }

            // Если событие помечено приложением как обработанное,
            // прервём дальнейшее распространение сообщения
            if (eventArgs.Handled)
                return 1;
        }

        // Вызовем следующий обработчик
        return WinAPI.User32.CallNextHookEx(_keyboardHookHandle, code, wParam, ref lParam);
    });

    _mouseCallback = new WinAPI.User32.MouseHookProc((int code,
        WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage wParam, ref WinAPI.User32.MouseHookStruct lParam) =>
    {
        // Если code < 0, мы не должны обрабатывать это сообщение системы
        if (code >= 0)
        {
            // В зависимости от типа пришедшего сообщения вызовем то или иное событие
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.MouseMove:
                    MouseMove(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.LeftButtonDown:
                    MouseButtonDown(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.RightButtonDown:
                    MouseButtonDown(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.MiddleButtonDown:
                    MouseButtonDown(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Middle, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.LeftButtonUp:
                    MouseButtonUp(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.RightButtonUp:
                    MouseButtonUp(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;

                case WinAPI.User32.WindowsMessage.MiddleButtonUp:
                    MouseButtonUp(this,
                        new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Middle, 0, lParam.X, lParam.Y, 0));
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Вызовем следующий обработчик
        return WinAPI.User32.CallNextHookEx(_mouseHookHandle, code, wParam, ref lParam);
    });

    // В SetWindowsHookEx следует передать дескриптор библиотеки user32.dll
    // Библиотека user32 всё равно всегда загружена в приложениях .NET,
    // хранить и освобождать дескриптор или что-либо ещё с ним делать нет необходимости
    IntPtr user32Handle = WinAPI.Kernel32.LoadLibrary("user32");

    // Установим хуки
    _keyboardHookHandle = WinAPI.User32.SetWindowsHookEx(
        WinAPI.User32.WindowsHook.KeyboardLowLevel, _keyboardCallback, user32Handle, 0);

    _mouseHookHandle = WinAPI.User32.SetWindowsHookEx(
        WinAPI.User32.WindowsHook.MouseLowLevel, _mouseCallback, user32Handle, 0);
}

#region IDisposable implementation

private bool _isDisposed = false;

public bool IsDisposed { get { return _isDisposed; } }

public void Dispose()
{
    if (_isDisposed)
        return;

    _isDisposed = true;

    // Удалим хуки
    WinAPI.User32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(_keyboardHookHandle);
    WinAPI.User32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(_mouseHookHandle);
}

~GlobalHook()
{
    Dispose();
}

#endregion
}
```

Вот пример использования хука

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
protected readonly GlobalHook hook = new GlobalHook();

...

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hook.KeyDown += (s, ev) => {
        // Так или иначе свернём приложение и т.д.,
        // при необходимости можно проверить, какая именно кнопка была нажата
        ...
    };

    // На hook.KeyUp, hook.MouseMove, hook.MouseButtonDown, hook.MouseButtonUp
    // можно повесить обработчики абсолютно точно так же

    // hook.MouseMove следует использовать осторожно,
    // оно вызывается достаточно большое число раз во время движения мыши
}
}
```

Программа отлавливает нажатые клавиши, но только если запущена под пользователем. А мне надо что бы она запускалась под админом или системой. Можно ли это как то решить?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать службу.

Comment: я его запускаю под системной учеткой. у него те же права что и у службы

Comment: А вы как знаете что программа ваша будет работать под другой учёткой? Вы её в автозапуск поставили? Если да - ваша програма активна только когда пользователь зашёл. А может автозапуск под другой учёткой не срабатывает?

Comment: я ее ставлю в автозапуск через групповые политики на компьютер, либо при запущенной сессии админа запускаю сессию юзера. В диспетчере задач она видна под учеткой System либо administrator. И все равно в сеансе пользователя она не срабатывает